# How to compile open ssl 1.1.1D source on as400 machine

Tags: openssl, ibm-midrange

I need to uplift open ssl version to 1.1.1D in our product. for that i need to compile open ssl 1.1.1D source code on AS400 OS. Can anybody help me on this.

i have downloaded open ssl source code from open ssl website.

Comment: You did not mention what have you tried by now. Didn't regular `./configure && make` work?

Comment: Previously i had uplifted 1.0.2D, i have added some commands in configure to make it compile on AS400.

Comment: i have added below commnad in configure file

Comment: "OS400-icc","icc:-v -O4 -DB_ENDIAN -DCHARSET_EBCDIC -DNO_SYS_PARAM_H -D_ALL_SOURCE -DNO_SYSLOG -qTGTRLS=V7R2M0 -qLOCALETYPE=*LOCALE -qSTGMDL=*INHERIT -qTERASPACE=*YES -qCSOPT=\\\"\\\'-qconvliteral=850\\\'\\\" -qENUM=*SMALL::-D_MULTI_THREADED:OS400:-v -qAUT=*ALL -qREPLACE=*YES -qALWLIBUPD=*YES -qTGTRLS=V7R2M0:THIRTY_TWO_BIT DES_PTR DES_UNROLL MD2_CHAR RC4_INDEX RC4_CHAR BF_PTR:${no_asm}::os400-shared::-v -qTGTRLS=V7R2M0:.so:true:-cuv",

Comment: But this is not working

Comment: if i run ./confgure, it ask for perl. i dont know much on AS400. as of now i need to uplift to 1.1.1D series whihc has many changes compare to 1.0.2D series.

Comment: If it requires perl, then try to install perl first. I found https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/home?lang=en#!/wiki/W1c12c273752d_4cb8_b000_8375ec43426d/page/OpenSSL%201.1.1%20Instructions so maybe OpenSSL did not drop support for your platform yet.

Comment: @madhusudhangl: Which version of the OS are you referring to? Also, maybe IBM already provides a newer version of OpenSSL in one way or the other.

Comment: @PoC i am using V7R2 for compilation. Actually i need to compile the open ssl source code on AS400.

Comment: @ahwayakchih Thanks for link.  but on AS400, once source code is compiled, it generates object files. those files will be combined to save files.

Comment: @madhusudhan gl: As Charles pointed out, it could be way easier for you to get precompiled packages from IBM. Could you elaborate why you need exactly 1.1.1D? What are you trying to achieve? Maybe we could help better when we get a broader picture of what's the exact culprit.

Comment: @PoC I have integrated latest open ssl to windows and linux platform for our project. i need to do the same for AS400. since 1.1.1D is latest from open ssl, i have taken source code from open ssl site.  i need to build libraries and use them in our project.

Comment: @Poc i have compiled in windows  and Unix platforms.  i dont have any idea on how to comopile on AS400 machine since there is no proper instruction for this plaforms.  you can download open ssl source code from https://www.openssl.org/source/

Comment: @madhusudhan gl: You didn't answer to Charles recommendation below. The package mentioned there isn't the most recent version but also on Linux you'll most likely find an older version with latest security patches applied. If you insist on the most recent version, you'll need to talk to IBM support and make them prepare a current version for you. Also, you did not answer to ahwayakchih, if his mentioned perl installation was successful for you. Please edit your question and write down step by step what you tried and copy-paste error messages, so we can try to resolve this apparent confusion.

Answer (score 1):

If you are actually using an AS-400, you're probably out of luck...

On the other hand, if you are using a modern IBM POWER server running a currently supported version of IBM i, you are in luck.

Simply install a recent version of [Access Client Solutions(ACS)](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/ibm-i-access-client-solutions)

Add a connection to your IBM i server, then go to tools->Open Source Package Manager

[image]

OpenSSL is one of the 261 currently offered packages
[image]

For more information about opensource on IBM i, look here
[IBM i opensource repo](https://bitbucket.org/ibmi/opensource/src/master/)

Comment: To my knowledge, the Term AS/400 is stuck, no matter what. It's much more important to mention the OS version people are trying stuff with. Ideally, it's most helpful if they're talking about the CL environment or PASE when they try to port stuff.